# Is gas fee paid for this transaction that was dropped?

Tags: gas, fees, failed-transaction

This is transaction that was supposed to fund a smart contract but because of a low gas fee that I set, it resulted in an error

[image]

Gas fees were around 10-15 usd, but still it wasn't enough.

I can't figure out whether or not I was charged gas fees for it. In other words, are gas fees charged for such failed trasactions or do they not?

Comment: Isn't this just a valid revert in the contract code? (_"Signature has expired"_) What makes you think the problem is related to gas? (You were charged $6.83)

Answer (score 2):

For transactions that are reverted by contracts (i.e. rejected because some problem with the inputs), a partial gas fee is charged up to the point contract execution was possible and you hit an invalid condition.

Answer (score 2):

Actually that is not an error from the blockchain itself, but from the contract you are calling: https://etherscan.io/address/0xede26ccc85ae521d06b5ef2604952a421c9124b6#code

So your transaction was processed, but reverted. You are charged for the gas used until the revert.